# spacy 2.0.12 / thinc 6.10.3 crashing django on heroku

Tags: python, django, pip, nlp, spacy

I'm having an issue with `v2.0.12` that I've traced into `thinc`. `pip list` shows me:

```
msgpack (0.5.6)
msgpack-numpy (0.4.3.1)
murmurhash (0.28.0)
regex (2017.4.5)
scikit-learn (0.19.2)
scipy (1.1.0)
spacy (2.0.12)
thinc (6.10.3)
```

I have code that works fine on my Mac, but fails in production. The stack trace goes into `spacy` and then into `thinc` -- and then django literally crashes. This all worked when I used an earlier version of spacy -- this has only come about since I'm attempting to upgrade to `v2.0.12`.

My requirements.txt file has these lines:

```
regex==2017.4.5
spacy==2.0.12
scikit-learn==0.19.2
scipy==1.1.0
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

The last line pulls the `en_core_web_sm` down during deployment. I'm doing this so I can get those models loaded on Heroku during deployment.

I then load the parser like this:

```
import en_core_web_sm
en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Then the stack trace shows the problem here in `thinc:`

```
File "spacy/language.py", line 352, in __call__
  doc = proc(doc)
File "pipeline.pyx", line 426, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.__call__
File "pipeline.pyx", line 438, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.predict
File "thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 161, in __call__
  return self.predict(x)
File "thinc/api.py", line 55, in predict
  X = layer(X)
File "thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 161, in __call__
  return self.predict(x)
File "thinc/api.py", line 293, in predict
  X = layer(layer.ops.flatten(seqs_in, pad=pad))
File "thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 161, in __call__
  eturn self.predict(x)
File "thinc/api.py", line 55, in predict
  X = layer(X)
File "thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 161, in __call__
  return self.predict(x)
File "thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 125, in predict
  y, _ = self.begin_update(X)
File "thinc/api.py", line 374, in uniqued_fwd
  Y_uniq, bp_Y_uniq = layer.begin_update(X_uniq, drop=drop)
File "thinc/api.py", line 61, in begin_update
  X, inc_layer_grad = layer.begin_update(X, drop=drop)
File "thinc/neural/_classes/layernorm.py", line 51, in begin_update
  X, backprop_child = self.child.begin_update(X, drop=0.)
File "thinc/neural/_classes/maxout.py", line 69, in begin_update
  output__boc = self.ops.batch_dot(X__bi, W)
File "gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 192, in handle_abort
  sys.exit(1)
```

Again -- this all works on my laptop.

Is there something wrong with how I'm loading? Or is my version of `thinc` out of date? If so, what should my `requirements.txt` file look like?

Comment: Filed issue with the `spacy` team: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue, but am leaving the answer in case someone else needs it.

The problem was that my thread was taking too long to respond because of how and when I was building and training my `sklearn` models. As a result, Heroku aborted the thread -- which is why the stack trace shows `abort`.

The fix was to change how and when I was loading the ML models so this particular operation didn't timeout.